# Path app timeline implementation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, implementation

Can somebody explain how the timeline of Path is implemented? Using UITableviewcell? Specifically I am interested in the nested text under the picture in the profile page? Is it a separate cell? And also how do you implement the timer that scroll with the scroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that second part of your question you should take a look at [TimeScroller on github](https://github.com/andrewroycarter/TimeScroller).